# How to identify the Actionfilter used in a Controller Action Method?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, action-filter

`OnActionExecuting` triggers when an action is about to execute.

If my action has actionfilter

```
[myCustomActionFilter]
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
//implementation
}
```

Is it possible to determine (inside the `OnActionExecuting` event) that an action has `myCustomActionFilter` applied into it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method above is case sensitive.

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    var actionDescriptor = filterContext.ActionDescriptor;
    if (actionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(myCustonActionFilter), true))
    {
        var attributeInstance = (myCustomActionFilter) actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(myCustomActionFilter), true);

    }   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
     public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
            {
                var controllerType = filterContext.Controller.GetType();
                var actionMethod = controllerType.GetMethod(filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName);
                if (actionMethod.IsDefined(typeof(myCustomActionFilter),true))
                {
                    var attributeInstance =
                        (myCustomActionFilter) actionMethod.GetCustomAttributes(typeof (myCustomAct   
ionFilter), true);
        }
```